JWT expires after refreshing page
I created a authentication system and thus was setting a JWT token in a cookie. However when I refresh the page it is getting deleted, even though I am setting it's expiry to be 24 hours.
jwt.sign(userData, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
  expiresIn: '1h'
}, (err, token) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  res.cookie('authToken', token, {
    maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // 24 hrs
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: true, // Set to true if using HTTPS
    sameSite: 'None', // Adjust as needed ('Strict', 'Lax', 'None')
    path: '/'
  });
  res.json({
    success: true,
    message: 'Login successful'
  });
});


I assume jwt.sign() is part of a library? Check it's documentation. It looks to me like you're setting expiration to 1 hour, not 24

Did you see the cookie value was set correctly in Application tab in the browser's devtool?

You’re setting httpOnly and secure on the cookie you’re dropping to the client; does this align with the environment in which you’re testing (i.e., not using the cookie in JavaScript and within a secure HTTPS context)? How have you affirmatively verified the token itself is expired immediately?

@kevinluo201 yes I did the cookie was getting added but as soon as I reload it was getting delete

Hi, Such cases need step by step checking. First of all, request please ensure that the cookie authToken has been physically stored in your Browser. This you can do it by checking the Cookies tab comes under Google Chrome/Application/Storage. If it is listed there, the the first part is success. The cookie has successfully completed the first half of its circulation. Now the second half of its circulation starts when the app is making another request with the same domain.

...Therefore please do the next request and immediately  check the response headers tab which also comes under Google Chrome/Network/Headers/Request headers. The header Cookie must include your cookie as well. If so, then the cookie has completed its full circulation. Please try this much if you think it may be useful.
